# Solidity: Convert from "bytes memory" to "address"

Tags: solidity, addresses, memory, bytes

I'm using solidity 0.5.0 and when i try to compile my contract it's giving me this error

```
Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes memory" to "address"
```

my code is this:

```
  /// @dev get broker address for endpoint
 function getEndpointBroker(address oracleAddress, bytes32 endpoint) public view returns (address) 
  {


return address(db.getBytes(keccak256(abi.encodePacked('oracles', oracleAddress, endpoint, 'broker'))));
}
```

Comment: what does db.getBytes(...) do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Omitted the function `db.getBytes()` to avoid compilation errors in remix. You can choose:

```
function getEndpointBroker(address oracleAddress, bytes32 endpoint) public view returns (address) {
        return address(uint160(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked('oracles', oracleAddress, endpoint, 'broker')))));
    }
```

Or:

```
function getEndpointBroker(address oracleAddress, bytes32 endpoint) public view returns (address) {
        return address(uint160(bytes20(keccak256(abi.encodePacked('oracles', oracleAddress, endpoint, 'broker')))));
    }
```

Edit: [Solidity doc](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.9/types.html#address).

> If you convert a type that uses a larger byte size to an `address`, for
>   example `bytes32`, then the `address` is truncated. To reduce conversion
>   ambiguity version 0.4.24 and higher of the compiler force you make the
>   truncation explicit in the conversion. Take for example the address
>   `0x111122223333444455556666777788889999AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFCCCC`.
>
> You can use `address(uint160(bytes20(b)))`, which results in
>   `0x111122223333444455556666777788889999aAaa`, or you can use
>   `address(uint160(uint256(b)))`, which results in
>   `0x777788889999AaAAbBbbCcccddDdeeeEfFFfCcCc`.